# MVC4 Registration Limit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, brute-force

I've developed a MVC4-project and deployed it (in bèta version). A visitor must login before he can see most of the website. For login, you are required to register. So far so good.
Now there's some weird dude who is trying to register a 100 times, it seems just to annoy me. How can I prevent this? I already have the following:

1. I have to manually accept registrations (as admin)
2. I integrated a captcha

So this dude is locked out from my application anyway, but his registration attempts are stored in my database, so it keeps expanding.

My question is: Is there any way to limit registration actions? Like only one time per hour or something like that?

Kind regards

Comment: Something wrong with your captcha.. seems like he is able to automate the registration. If he is submitting the registration manually... then let him be.. he obviously needs a hug or something.. But seriously.. something is wrong with your captcha.

Comment: It doesn't seem like a bot, he writes usernames like asdfasdf and sometimes he uses my name. So it seems more like he's the hug-wanting kind. The best thing to do is just ignore him? And manually delete his records of the database?

Comment: use registration activator! so each activated/accepted user will be used.

Comment: It is up to you. How hard it is to delete those records.. let him have the fun for a week and then delete the record.. it wont take even 1 minute to delete. Smile while deleting it knowing someone out there is interested with your system.

Comment: Also maybe the guy is a legitimate user, and he is having trouble registering into the system, maybe your system fails during registration, etc.. have you thought of that?

Answer (score 1):

You can store ip in database after registration for one hour. And before registration check if ip exists in database. Or create application level list of IPs instead of DB.

Comment: IP is inaccurate.. if he is using some starbuck wifi then the whole starbuck cannot register into the system for one hour. Plus it is not worth the effort. Just ignore the loser.